# How to Merge a Chinese-Only Doc and Its Translated English-Only Doc into A Chinese-English Bilingual Paragraph-by-Paragraph Doc

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, language

I translated a source document in Chinese into a target English document with a CAT (computer-aided translation) tool OmegaT. So, there are two documents, one is a Chinese document, and the other is an English document with the same structure, format, etc. They are basically the same except they are in different languages.

Now I want to merge the two documents into a single document, in which Chinese and its translation go paragraph-by-paragraph. And for content in a cell of table, it is the same: Chinese comes first with English translation following it.

An example goes like this: https://docs.zoho.com/file/mb9ur1aaa16a336b44f5b8785007aaaeaabc4

Is there any way to do it quickly or automatically or with Macro? Any response will be much appreciated. This problem has been existing for two years. And I have googled it, but no help.